# Error: pg_config executable not found

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

Я работал на ОС Windows 10 и пытался установить psycopg2. Я сделал "pip install psycopg2" и у меня вылетела ошибка

```
Collecting psycopg2
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/84/d7/6a93c99b5ba4d4d22daa3928b983cec66df4536
ca50b22ce5dcac65e4e71/psycopg2-2.8.4.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    running egg_info
    creating pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info
    writing pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info\top_level.txt
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'

    Error: pg_config executable not found.

    pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
    containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
    option:

        python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

    or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.

    If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI
    'psycopg2-binary' package instead.

    For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
    <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html>).
```

Я добавил путь к pg_config в моей переменной окружения, так как там указано, что исполняемый файл pg_config не найден, но толку от этого не было. Сейчас я не знаю что нужно делать и буду признателен вашей помощи в решении этой проблемы.

**Попытка ввести 'pip install psycopg2-binary' приводит к аналогичной ошибке**

---

Короче, решил проблему я давно. Я просто перешел на линукс.

Comment: В той консоли, из которой запускаете `pip install psycopg2`, выведите и проверьте содержимое Вашей переменной PATH командой `set PATH`, а также попытайтесь запустить `pg_config`

Comment: Я тоже столкнулся с данной проблемой. Если Вы нашли решение, то напишите как исправили. Спасибо )

Answer (score 0):

Я нашел решение данной проблемы для Windows 10. Установил PostgreSQL 12 и добавил этот путь (в моем случае это C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin). Это автоматически добавило путь в pg_config и проблема была решена.

Comment: И еще одно решение данной проблемы... Сначала обновите pip до актуального состояния. Если не получается через env окружение,  обновитесь из командной строки (CMD): python -m pip install -U pip Потом установите из той же командной строки сам psycopg2: python -m pip install psycopg2==2.8.4 У меня все прошло хорошо. Хотя до этого мучался пару дней (пробовал через PyCharm установить)

Comment: После обновления pip до последней версии 20* в PyCharm уже смог нормально установить psycopg2